# Create a Matrix from an ArrayList

Tags: java, math, matrix, arraylist

I want to create a class that creates a Matrix via an ArrayList.

So that's what I did:

```
public class Matrice implements IMatrice {

ArrayList elements;
private int numLignes;
private int numColonnes;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrice test = new Matrice(3, 4, 6.0);
    System.out.println(test);
}

public Matrice (int numLignes, int numColonnes, double valeur){
    this.numLignes = numLignes;
    this.numColonnes = numColonnes;
    elements = new ArrayList(numLignes * numColonnes);
    for(int i = 0; i < numLignes * numColonnes; i++){
        elements.add(i, valeur);
    }
}
}
```

Now that i created this, I wanted to try if it works. Then I created this `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    final DecimalFormat DEC_FORMAT = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    final int ESP = 8; 
    int num;
    String sTmp;
    String s = "[";
    for (int i = 0 ; i < (numLignes * numColonnes) ; i++) {
       //etendre i sur ESP colonnes
       sTmp = "";
       num =  ESP - DEC_FORMAT.format(elements.get(i)).length();
       for (int j = 0 ; j < num ; j++) {
          sTmp = sTmp + " ";
       }
       sTmp = sTmp + DEC_FORMAT.format(elements.get(i));

       if (i != 0 && i % numColonnes == 0) {
          s = s + "  ]\n[" + sTmp; 
       } else {
          s = s + sTmp;
       }
    }
    s = s + "  ]";
    return s;
 }
```

Then this is my main to try the Matrix:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matrice test = new Matrice(3, 4, 6.0);
    System.out.println(test);
}
```

and i don't know why but i only get this :

```
[  ]
```

I know that a little thing is wrong but I can't find what. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i messed up...

The problem was in here :

```
elements.add(i, valeur);
```

i did a mistake... i mingled with the set() method.

here is the correction :

```
elements.add(valeur);
```